# How to get native android jelly bean Camera app working from source code?

Tags: android, android-source

It seems jelly bean Camera is part of Gallery2 and are in separate branches, although somehow mesh together. I've got the sources for them from android.googlesource.com but I can't seem to get them working. I could copy and paste the codes from one branch to another and get that whole mess working somewhat, but I'm sure there must be a better approach (since google engineers must have a way of getting this working), and it must just be a gap in my knowledge about android. Any hints appreciated.